# All lists with class="sub-menu" get the same background, Need help removing

Tags: css, wordpress

A snippet from my Wordpress view:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul id="menu-main-navigation">
    <li id="menu-item-646" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#" class="">MAIN MENU ITEM<span class="downarrowclass"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-661" class="menu-item menu-item-661"><a href="#">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

The background is styled with the following CSS snippet:

```
#menu li.current-menu item a {
background: url(images/menu-tip.png) center top no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is this background is also on every single Sub-menu item. How should I change my CSS selector to only target the main items?

**Answers below worked great, thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**

```
#menu li.current-menu-item > a {
background: url(http://lsst.astro.washington.edu/intro/imsim/images/ImageSimNoBackgroundSmall.png) center top no-repeat;
}
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u53Bx/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick. Thank you for the Fiddle Demo, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#menu li.current-menu-item > a {
   background: url(images/menu-tip.png) center top no-repeat;
}
```

`>` is the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

Comment: Thank you so much and thank you for the educational education, I love you!